# Transformation formula of hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions

I think it's easier to ask your help about my secial case. So, can you please help me to find a relationship wetween $ _2F_1  (1,1,2-2/a; \frac{1}{1+\frac{R^a}{u.s.P}}) \;$  and $\; _2F_1  (1,1,2-2/a; \frac{1}{1+R^{a/2}}) $.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the $a,b,c$ in your $f(z)$ the same as the numerator and denominator parameters in your Gaussian hypergeometric function?

Comment: Oh No ... Sorry me, I will update the question with my special case :)

Comment: I think you can use functional composition.  BTW: what is $u.s.P$ ?